# SQL HAVING Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using WHERE XXX IN (SQL), so (SQL) must select only one Column

In this case I'm select some `customer_id` from a group, and those customer only belongs to that group only

```
WHERE `id_customer` IN(
SELECT g.`id_customer` // this must select *only one* column
FROM ps_customer_group AS g
Group By g.`id_customer`
Having COUNT(g.`id_customer`) = 1
AND  g.`id_group`=3  // **- Unknown column 'g.id_group' in 'having clause'** 
)
```

the raw data look like this, btw this is not the result 
[image]

Comment: First of all you are grouping by `id_customer` and searching for having count = 1. So it will return you more than one values.

Comment: nono, this is raw data not the result, the sql I run only display syntax error

Comment: I didn't understand completely, you want to know if the user belongs to only one group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE id_customer IN(

    select g.id_customer from
    ps_customer_group as g
    where g.id_group=3 -- That belongs to this group
    and g.id_customer in(

       SELECT g.id_customer
       FROM ps_customer_group AS g 
       Group By g.id_customer 
       Having COUNT(g.id_group) = 1 -- is his only group
    )

)
```

Here is a [test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/400347/28)

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to know if a customer belongs to one group (ID=3) only, you have to change your query:

```
select g.id_customer
  from ps_customer_group AS g 
 where g.id_customer in (
         select id_customer 
           from ps_customer_group 
          where id_group=3
       )
 Group By g.id_customer 
Having COUNT(distinct g.id_group) = 1
```

this will list all customers which belong to group #3 and to no other group.